# How would I connect to a SQL Server (running in a VM using Ubuntu Server), using Access or Visual Studio on my host?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, ms-access, ubuntu, visual-studio

I have tried to connect various ways already and have not been successful. I need a more specific guide on how to/if you can connect this way. I have specific limitations that you need to account for, however. I cannot enable port forwarding on my router in any fashion and I cannot install anything unportable. I'd prefer to connect to the SQL Server via Access. It's worth noting that the VM and the host run on the same machine.

I simply tried connecting via the VM's IP and that didn't work. I made sure the 'bind-address' was set to listen on all interfaces. I also allowed both ports 3306 and 1433 open in my VM. I have a feeling that I'm complicating all of it, so in essence, I just want to know how to connect to a SQL database on a VM via my host. Obviously, ask questions as I know my question may come off a little unclear. I am also willing to share more details if needed.

Server version: 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.22.04.1

I have the network settings set to bridged adapter in Oracle VM.

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Are you using Microsoft SQL Server or MySQL as the DBMS on Ubuntu? They are not the same. Please [edit] the tags in your question. Thanks.

Comment: What error messages are you getting as you try to connect. What is your hostname? Is it IP or DNS based. Have you checked if those ports are open on the Ubuntu SQL Server?